# I'm trying to make a sequence in google sheets that repeats over and over, but can't come up with a formula that works

Tags: google-sheets

I found this formula on this website that helps me out with one of my columns on a google sheet I'm working on.

=transpose(split(REPT(concat(JOIN(",",SEQUENCE(1,6)),","),ROUNDDOWN(ROWS(E3:E)/6)),",",true))

Another column I need to make does exactly this, but each number is repeated 6 times before moving on to the next number. ie. 111111222222333333444444555555111111222222333333444444555555 etc.

How would I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in lambda and repeat 6x:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, x&x&x&x&x&x)
 (TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCAT(JOIN(",", 
 SEQUENCE(1,6)),","), ROUNDDOWN(ROWS(E3:E)/6)), ",", 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(E3:E))/6,0))
```

You can change E3:E to your actual range

Comment: With that same logic your first formula could be written as: =ARRAYFORMULA (MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(E3:E),1,0),6)+1)